# "input type = file" not giving file object in Internet Explorer 9 or lower browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, file-upload

HTML source

```
<input id="UploadFile" type="file" name="UploadFile" />
<button type="button" onclick="UploadDocument();" class="RemoveButtonDefaultStyle">
```

Javascript function

```
function UploadDocument() {
var fileInput = document.getElementById('UploadFile');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/ControllerName/Action?id=14671');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
//Appending file information in Http headers
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', fileInput.files[0].name);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type', fileInput.files[0].type);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Description', $("#UploadDescription").val());
//Sending file in XMLHttpRequest
xhr.send(fileInput.files[0]);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    $("#UploadFile").val('');
    $("#UploadDescription").val('')
    $("#UploadedFilesDiv").html(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
return false;  }
```

This works fine in IE10, Chrome, and Firefox.. but it fails for IE 9 or lower version browsers. The error says "files[0]" is undefined
I know File is an HTML5 object which is not supported in IE 9 or lower browser. Can any one please suggest what could be the easiest workaround for this?

Comment: The file API is supported only in IE >= 10 see [MDN File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: yes, I know. but there must be some work around to get it working on IE9, or IE8

Comment: because, IE 9 is still widely used browser, and if someone develops a website that runs for IE 10, they would obviously like it to successfully run on IE 9.

Comment: The only workaround is to develop a iframe based solution as done by frameworks like [jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)